# Define different output for the _repr_ method when printing a list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, repr, python-class

I have a custom class which has implemented the `_repr_` method, printing out all the properties of this object, for example:

```
Id: XXX,
Name: XXX 
PropA: XXX,
PropB: XXX,
PropC: XXX ...
```

**Problem -**

Is there a way to change the output to return only a subset of the properties, when printing a list of these objects,  for example:

```
Id: XXX,
Name: XXX
```

**My Ideology** -The only possible way I can think of implementing this would be to implement a custom list class for the object which implements the less detailed output of `_repr_`, however, I would rather avoid this if possible.

Comment: `print([obj1, obj2, obj3])` will use `__repr__`, whereas `print(*[obj1, obj2, obj3])`, which unpacks the list first, will use `__str__`, so one solution would be to override `__str__` to return the short version and use `print(*lst_of_objects)` if you want to reserve `__repr__` for the long version.

Comment: Your class should not behave differently based on circumstances. If you want a more minimal repr, explicitly create a method that returns one, and explicitly use like `print([o.min_repr() for o in lst])`.